# Sabre PNR creation issue Invalid Action

Tags: c#-4.0

```
OTA_AirAvailLLSRQ
EnhancedAirBookRQ
TravelItineraryAddInfoRQ ( add passenger details)
TravelItineraryReadRQ (Confirm Passenger Details)
EndTransactionRQ
```

These steps should have same session. After EndTransactionRQ, I should get PNR as a result.

I have done the step1 but in the step 2 i am facing issue `invalid action`.
I used msgHeader.Action = "EnhancedAirBookRQ";

Comment: please provide a solution if you have any idea about the issue

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.